# Find which device node an entry in lsusb output corresponds to

Tags: linux, lsusb

I need to use `lsusb` to determine the type of USB connection my USB has to know if `dd` is working at full speed. I read that to do this I need to use `lsusb -t`, but the output doesn't tell me which device node each entry corresponds to. How do I figure that out?

Comment: If this is connected to "make dd faster": The limit is the write speed of the storage medium, which is a *lot* slower than most USB speeds. So even if you could somehow make sure the USB speed is ok, it wouldn't help you: The limit is still the write speed of the storage medium.

Answer (score 1):

lsusb -t seems to provide a tree which lists "Dev X" - this corresponds to device "00X" in a standard "lsusb" listing.

Another alternative would be to use lsusb -v which "includes configuration descriptors for the devices current speed".

Comment: You should mention that `lsusb -t` includes the speed of the particular device at the end (480M/12M/5000M).

Comment: Yes, but other than the bus number, that doesn't list any of the same information as `lsusb` without the `-t`, so unless the driver or device class is unique enough to give it away, there's no way to match it to a device name listed by `lsusb`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fiddling with this for a while, here's a script I came up with to map the lsusb output to /sys. It seems to work for me but I haven't tested it extensively yet.

(Note: I'm not having much luck formatting this, so you might have to add some newlines or whatever)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# usb2sys - find lsusb device in /sys file system
#

die()
{
    echo "$@"
    exit 1
}

[[ $# -lt 1 ]] && die "need vendor and product ids (from lsusb) as dddd:dddd"

vendor=${1%:*}
product=${1##*:}

sys=/sys/bus/usb/devices/
cd $sys

for d in *; do
    path=$sys/$d
    if [ -f $path/idProduct ]; then
      prod=$( cat $path/idProduct )
      vend=$( cat $path/idVendor )

      if [ $prod = $product -a $vend = $vendor ]; then
        echo prod = $prod
        echo vend = $vend
        echo /sys device is $path
        cat $path/power/wakeup
        echo ""
      fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: The usage of `[ … -a … ]` is discouraged; you should say `if [ "$prod" = "$product" ] && [ "$vend" = "$vendor" ]`.

Comment: sigh... the language police strike again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no single command or utility that will give you the information. You have to rummage for the information under `/sys`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493858/linux-how-to-map-a-blockdevice-to-a-usb-device for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of *lsusb -t* for my system:

```
    # lsusb -t
    /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
    /:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
    /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=asix, 480M
```

The only mass storage device is located at Bus 02, Port 03, and it is served by the driver *xhci_hcd*, which is the proper Linux driver for USB3.0 devices. To the best of my knowledge, this si the only reference you will find to speed, here.

The above can be double-checked as follows. Since you are searching for a *block* device, go to */sys/class/block*, where you can find:

```
# cd /sys/class/block/
root@debS:/sys/class/block# ls
loop0  loop2  loop4  loop6  sda   sda2  sda6  sdb
loop1  loop3  loop5  loop7  sda1  sda5  sda7  sdb1
```

Assuming you are interested in block device *sdb*, now you determine the bus address as follows:

```
# cd sdb; cd $(realpath $PWD); echo $PWD
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb
```

This (bus2, port 3) jibes with the above.